# Is there a way of grouping or reducing this array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

Example below, getting total math values corresponding to the same values of `period_str` key.

```
[
     {math: 40, period_str: "Period 1, 03 2019"},
     {math: 32, period_str: "Period 1, 03 2019"},
     {math: 44, period_str: "Period 1, 02 2020"},
]
```

Expected output

```
[
{math: 72, period_str: "Period 1, 03 2020"}
{math: 44, period_str: "Period 1, 02 2020"}
]
```

Or
output (object only)

```
{math: 72, period_str: "Period 1, 03 2020"}
{math: 44, period_str: "Period 1, 02 2020"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `period_str` as a unique key:

```js
const arr = [
 {math: 40, period_str: "Period 1, 03 2019"},
 {math: 32, period_str: "Period 1, 03 2019"},
 {math: 44, period_str: "Period 1, 02 2020"},
]

const out = arr.reduce((a, v) => {
  if(a[v.period_str]) {
    a[v.period_str].math += v.math
  } else {
    a[v.period_str] = v
  }
  return a
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(out))
```